# Find Index of Last Occurence in Multidimensional Array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I use the following code to add new values to my array.
I'd like however to be able to insert values after a certain match.

```
var Arr = [];
a = document.getElementById("f").value;
b = document.getElementById("s").value;
c = document.getElementById("t").value;

Arr.push([f,s,t])
```

If for example the first element in my array contains a value that's equal to the value in "a", I'd like the new value ("a") to be inserted right after the last occurrence of that particular value in the array

for example the following array:

```
["OPEL", "BLACK", "4"] 
["OPEL", "BLUE", "5"] 
["OPEL", "RED", "4"] 
["FIAT", "BLACK", "5"] 
["FIAT", "WHITE", "5"] 
["FORD", "GREY", "4"]
```

Now I'd like to insert the following item:

```
["FIAT", "ORANGE", "4"]
```

It needs to be inserted after the last occurrence of "FIAT", so the result will be:

```
["OPEL", "BLACK", "4"] 
["OPEL", "BLUE", "5"] 
["OPEL", "RED", "4"] 
["FIAT", "BLACK", "5"] 
["FIAT", "WHITE", "5"] 
["FIAT", "ORANGE", "4"] 
["FORD", "GREY", "4"]
```

Any ideas?

Comment: what effort have you made to solving the problem?

Comment: Easy. Just use `Array.prototype.splice()` to insert the array into where you want. Longer answer coming up!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you proposed, we have the following array:

```
var arr = [
        ["OPEL", "BLACK", "4"],
        ["OPEL", "BLUE", "5"],
        ["OPEL", "RED", "4"],
        ["FIAT", "BLACK", "5"], 
        ["FIAT", "WHITE", "5"],
        ["FORD", "GREY", "4"]
];
```

Then, we want to put the following child after the last occurrence of an array with the same first element as it:

```
var child = ["FIAT", "ORANGE", "4"];
```

To do this, we just traverse the array and we insert `child` after we find an array with the same first element as it, then we find the first array without the same first element. If we haven't inserted it by the end of the array, we insert it at the end.

```
//Create an insert method of arr:
arr.insert = function(child) {
    //This Bool is true iff we've found an array that has the same first element as it:
    var foundSameFirstElement = false;
    //Traverse arr:
    for (var i = 0; i < this.length; i++) {
        //If we haven't found an array with the same first element as child and this element has the same first element as child, then set foundSameFirstElement to true:
        if (!foundSameFirstElement && this[i][0] === child[0]) {
            foundSameFirstElement = true;
        }
        //If we have found an array with the same first element as child and this element does not have the same first element as child, then insert child into the array here and break to exit the loop:
        if (foundSameFirstElement && this[i][0] !== child[0]) {
            this.splice(i, 0, child);
            break;
        }
    }
    //If i is this.length, then we traversed the whole loop without breaking, meaning we haven't inserted child yet. Thus, if i is this.length, insert child at the end:
    if (i === this.length) this.splice(this.length, 0, child);
};
//Now to finish it off, pass child through arr.insert:
arr.insert(child);
//If we check the value of arr, it is just like how we want it to be, with child as index 5:
console.log(arr);
```

Comment: Thank you for you help Noble Mushtak! I find it hard to understand your code, so need some time to play with it. (new to JS and trying to learn it). thanks again!

Comment: No problem! I also had a lot of trouble with JavaScript when I was first starting up, so glad I could help a newcomer! If you need any clarifications with understanding it, just comment here again.

Comment: I am playing around with your solution, trying to make sense of it and looking for other ways to get to the same result as part of learning JS.

I'm trying to get the index of the item that has an matching 1st element value in the previous item but hasn't got an 1st element match in the current. Problem is that I get keep on getting an error (Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined)
Can you tell me why I am getting this error

for (var j = 0; j < arr.length; j++) {
  if (arr[j][0] !== child[0] && arr[j-1][0] === child[0]) {
            alert(j);
  } 
 }

Comment: This will fail if `j` is `0` because `arr[j-1]` is `arr[-1]` and thus `undefined` (because `-1` is negative and you can't get the negative index of an array). This means that `arr[j-1][0]` is `undefined[0]` which doesn't make any sense to the JavaScript compiler, thus the error. Instead, start `j` from `1`: `for (var j = 1; j < arr.length; j++) { [...] }`.